# Facebook publish_stream code ends up in a loop

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have the following code which works fine as long as in a previous part of the application, the user accepts the applications request to `publish_stream`.

```
# The facebook library
require_once("/var/www/facebook-php-sdk-master/src/facebook.php");

# Create facebook object
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = 'appId_here';
$config['secret'] = 'secret_here';
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

$facebook = new Facebook($config); 

$user_id = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user_id) {

    try {

        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');

        #check permissions
        $api_call = array(
                'method' => 'users.hasAppPermission',
                'uid' => $user_id,
                'ext_perm' => 'publish_stream'
        );

        #set to true if true...
        $can_offline = $facebook -> api( $api_call );

        #is it true?
        if( $can_offline ) {

            $post =  array(
                'message' => 'post_a_message'
            );

            $facebook->api('/' . $_GET["id"] . '/feed', 'POST', $post);

        } else {

            // can't post message - don't have permission

        }

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

        error_log($e);
        exit;

    }

} else {

    error_log("user not logged in");
    exit;

}
```

To try to resolve this, I attempted to insert the following code into the `else statement` which currently in the code above only contains the comment `// can't post message - don't have permission`

The code I tried to insert into that `else` was this:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => 'publish_stream' ) );
header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
```

That works as long as the user accepts to allow my app to `publish_stream`.  However, if the user does not accept, my app will keep asking the user to accept `publish_stream`.  How do I stop that loop from happening if the user decides not to accept?

Comment: I guess it is becuase you have not specified the return url, Return url is the one which you need to specify in your fb app as well as in your code, so that user will return to this page in both the condition whether  he accepts or rejects the permission, Please check my answer, which is in Graph API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working code : Please check it :

Page name : events.php

You can see `$redirect_uri = https://localhost/facebook_page/events.php` it is returning back to same page.

```
<?php

$facebook_appid         = "your appid";                     // Facebook appplication id
$facebook_secret        = "your app secret";                // Facebook secret id
$redirect_uri           = "https://localhost/facebook_page/events.php";   // return url to our application after facebook login ## should be SAME as in facebook application
$scope                  = "publish_stream"; // User permission for facebook

$profile_id             = "profile_id";// Where do you want to post it(profile id - It is a number)

$code                   = $_REQUEST["code"]?$_REQUEST["code"]:"";

if(empty($code)) {
    $_SESSION['state']  = rand(); // CSRF protection
    $dialog_url         = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=". $facebook_appid . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($redirect_uri) . "&state=". $_SESSION['state'] . "&scope=".$scope;
    header("location:".$dialog_url);
}

if($_SESSION['state'] && ($_SESSION['state'] == $_REQUEST['state'])) {
    $token_url          = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?". "client_id=" . $facebook_appid . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($redirect_uri). "&client_secret=" . $facebook_secret . "&code=" . $code;
    $response           = @file_get_contents($token_url);

    $params             = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);

    $access_token       = $params['access_token'];


}

?>

<!-- Here you can use 
      message, picture, link, name, caption, description, source, place, tags 
     as input fields-->

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $profile_id;?>/feed?access_token=<?php echo $access_token; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="message" value="test" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

You can post it using jquery also.

Answer (score 4):

As far as i remember, `$facebook -> getLoginUrl` can take parameter `cancel_url`, which contains the link, where user should be redirected if he doesn't give your app permissions.

So the code will be something like this

```
$login_url = $facebook -> getLoginUrl( array(
'scope' => 'publish_stream',
'cancel_url' => YOUR_LINK_HERE
));
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to redirect to that url if cancelled.  It keeps going to the original page.

Comment: Hmm, with changes they made to permissions page this might not work anymore, i'll try to find the way it's done now.

Comment: I've updated my sample code, as it's no longer `req_perms`, it's now `scope`.

Comment: I assume `cancel_url` still doesn't do the trick after you updated code?

Comment: I've tried both `cancel_url` and `cancel_uri` where the url is a different url i.e: `http://www.google.com/` and both times, it goes back to the page which initiates the call.

Comment: Why was this answer up-voted, it doesn't answer the question at all!

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code to check if the user has allowed publishing permisions or not:

```
$permissions = $facebook->api('me/permissions');
if( array_key_exists('publish_stream', $permissions['data'][0]) ) {
    //Continue with posting on users wall
} else {
    //Continue without posting on users wall
}
```